# Why can't I use my custom Powershell module in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am writing a small GUI in Visual Studio 2010 to be used with one of the custom modules I made for windows powershell, but unfortunately the only modules I can use with this are default ones (e.g. ActiveDirectory).

Here is the code that is supposed to run, but it does not do anything!  I have some code successfully running, but I can't post that for it has sensitive info.

Please help me, this is making me want to quit and become a Macintosh administrator

```
    private void getStateOfSelectedLab(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stateBox.Items.Clear();

        stateBox.Items.Add("Please Wait (This may take a few minutes)...");

        using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("import-module ActiveDirectory");  //import modules
            PowerShellInstance.Invoke();    //executes command pipeline

            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("import-module LANModule");
            PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-LabState " + selectLab.SelectedItem.ToString());
            //PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("lab", selectLab.SelectedItem.ToString());

            Collection<PSObject> theState = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

            string[] stateOfLab = new string[theState.Count];

            int i = 0;

            foreach (PSObject result in theState)
            {
                string aResult = result.ToString();

                stateOfLab[i] = aResult;
                i++;
            }

            stateBox.Items.Clear();

            //stateBox.Items.Add(theState.Count);

            stateBox.Items.AddRange(stateOfLab);
        }
    }
```

And here is the script that works:

```
        using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("import-module ActiveDirectory");  //import modules
            PowerShellInstance.Invoke();    //executes command pipeline

            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("import-module LANModule");
            PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

            //add another to the pipe, this one grabs all labs
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("$OU = [REDACTED]");
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript("Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter * -SearchBase $OU | sort-object");

            //returned collection of labs
            Collection<PSObject> allLabs = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();

            foreach (PSObject lab in allLabs)
            {
                string[] toks = lab.ToString().Split(',');
                string labName = toks[0].Substring(3);
                selectLab.Items.Add(labName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the lab names don't have spaces, do they?

Comment: After this line `Collection<PSObject> theState = PowerShellInstance.Invoke();` executes examine `PowerShellInstance.Streams.Errors` in the debugger.  If there was a non-terminating error that is how you can see it.